# Twilio Programmable Video API - Room Creation

Tags: twilio

I am currently working on a node app and using Twilio Programmable video api to create rooms: here is code

```
twilioClient.video.rooms.create({
            type: 'group',
            uniqueName: uniqueName,
            maxParticipants: maxParticipants,
            endTime: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 500000).toISOString(),
            duration: 100
        }).then(room => {
            console.log("room is >>>>:", room);
```

I am setting duration for 100, but the calls are working for a duration of 5 minutes only.

This is the json object for calls:

```
{
  sid: 'xxxxxxx',
  status: 'in-progress',
  dateCreated: 2020-08-26T18:58:11.000Z,
  dateUpdated: 2020-08-26T18:58:11.000Z,
  accountSid: 'xxxxxxx',
  enableTurn: true,
  uniqueName: 'workout-8940715',
  uniqueName: 'workout-8940715',
  statusCallback: null,
  statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
  endTime: null,
  duration: null,
  type: 'group',
  maxParticipants: 12,
  recordParticipantsOnConnect: true,
  videoCodecs: [ 'H264', 'VP8' ],
  mediaRegion: 'us1',
  url: 'https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms/xxxxx',
  links: {
    recordings: 'https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms/xxxxxx/Recordings',
    participants: 'https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms/xxxxxx/Participants'
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is it this? Also [duration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource) is seconds. The API response says:

```
  endTime: null,   duration: null,
```

> First join timeout: the first Participant must join within 5 minutes
> after Room creation. Otherwise the Room is destroyed.

[The Room Rest API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#the-rooms-rest-api)